# SQLite v1.0.115 vs v1.0.116

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am having problems upgrading SQLite from v1.0.115 to v1.0.116 in Visual Studio 2022 with VB.Net, Debug, Any CPU.
To test this, I made two identical test-projects. In one I installed System.Data.SQLite v1.0.115 via the NuGet Package Manager. In the other I installed v1.0.116 in the same way.

In v1.0.115 the following line is fine:

```
    conn.LoadExtension("SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init")
```

but in v1.0.116 I get an error for that line: The specified procedure could not be found.

I did see a post that suggested adding the full path to the Interop file, so I tried:

```
    conn.LoadExtension(Application.StartupPath() & "\bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init")
```

but this gives an error for that line:  The specified module could not be found.

For reference, my full function is:

```
    Public Function Connect(ByVal DBnum As Integer) As SQLiteConnection
        Dim conn As New SQLiteConnection
        Dim DBpath As String = Application.StartupPath() & "\hamdata.db3"
        Try
            conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & DBpath & ";Version=3;")

            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                conn.Open()
                conn.EnableExtensions(True)
                conn.LoadExtension("SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Message:" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
            Debug.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Source:" & vbCrLf & ex.Source)
            Debug.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "StackTrace:" & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
            Debug.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "TargetSite:" & vbCrLf & ex.TargetSite.ToString())
            MsgBox("Connection to Database " & DBnum & " at '" & DBpath & "' has Failed! Message: " & ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return conn
    End Function
```

Comment: `Application.StartupPath()` may not be what you expect it to be: just put `File.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath(), "\bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll")` into a variable and put a debug point there to find out what it ends up as.

Comment: The first line indicates that the DLL is in the same folder as the EXE. `Application.StartupPath` IS that folder, so why are you specifying a subfolder? Also, it's a property, not a method, so you don't put parentheses after it.

Comment: @user18387401 - no, the 'SQLite.Interop.dll' is never in the same folder as the exe, but with v1.0.115 it works fine. I tried adding or removing parentheses: it makes no difference.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Path.Combine' didn't work at all, for some reason!

```
    Debug.WriteLine(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "\bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll"))
```

returned: \bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll

```
    Debug.WriteLine(Application.StartupPath)
```

returned: C:\Programming\SQLite\SQLite_v1.0.116_TestBed\bin\Debug

```
    Debug.WriteLine(Application.StartupPath & "\bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll")
```

returned: C:\Programming\SQLite\SQLite_v1.0.116_TestBed\bin\Debug\bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll

Both of the following lines:

```
    conn.LoadExtension(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "\bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll"), "sqlite3_json_init")
    conn.LoadExtension(Application.StartupPath & "\bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init")
```

returned the error: 'The specified module could not be found.'
so I feel that the path-changes are a red-herring. As mentioned before,

```
    conn.LoadExtension("SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init")
```

returns the error: 'The specified procedure could not be found.'
which might indicate that the file 'SQLite.Interop.dll' has been found, but the internal procedure was not.

Following a suggestion in another post, I then deleted both the 'x64' and 'x86' folders in the Debug folder, and then did a 'Build'. The folders and their 'SQLite.Interop.dll' files were replaced, but the 'The specified procedure could not be found.' error continued, so I am no further forward!

---

SUCCESS

---

It appears that the problem is to do with the extension's entry point, for which I was using "sqlite3_json_init". The documentation says you can leave this argument blank and the extension loader logic will attempt to figure out the entry point on its own, but when I tried it I just got the 'The specified procedure could not be found.' error again. After some more searching, I found someone mentioning the entry point "sqlite3_fts5_init". I tried this in the line:

```
    conn.LoadExtension("SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_fts5_init")
```

and everything seems to be working again!